How transform Dp to Pixels in common layes of kotlin multiplatform?
Compose offers tools for creating user interfaces. It uses Dp for all elements, but performs callbacks using Px. Fine. I want to have a good method for converting sizes.
I'd prefer don't write specific function for all platforms.
Well common layer don't have accsess for LocalDensity.


Usually dp or its float pixel value will never leave your composables, so there shouldn't be a need for what you are asking. Can you better describe why this is even a relevant problem for you? The only thing I can think of would be where the actual pixel position has meaning for your business logic, e.g. the state of a game that you display in a Canvas. But then you would do the transformation between dp and pixels in Compose and only store an abtracted value in the lower layers.

I have two different monitors on my pc. One of them have scale 150%. When I try set "draggable" function "rememberDraggableState { sizeInDp ->  myOffset += sizeInDp }". It works differently on different screens. On screen where 150% I have sizeInDp = 1.5f insted of 1f. So the element moovs faster then coursor.

That seems like a problem that needs to be solved in Compose, and there you have access to LocalDensity. So what exactly is it that you need help with?

I can get "LocalDensity" in Android layer, but I write one UI for all devices. There is no "LocalDensity" in common layer, as LocalContext for android or somthing else specific for some platform.

So I decided to add invisible element in root screen that helps calculate dp scale.
object SizeObserver {


    private val _oneDp = MutableStateFlow(1f)
    val oneDP = _oneDp.asStateFlow()
    val oneDpValue get() = _oneDp.value

    @Composable
    operator fun invoke() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(10.dp)
                .onSizeChanged { _oneDp.value = it.width / 10f }
        )
    }


}

Switch on it in root.
@Composable
fun App() {
    SizeObserver()
}

Now you can use it for your draggable elements.
    var offsetHorizontal by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val horizontalDraggable = rememberDraggableState { offsetHorizontal += it / SizeObserver.oneDpValue }
    Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .offset(x = offsetHorizontal.dp)
                .draggable(horizontalDraggable, orientation = Orientation.Horizontal)
                
        )

